# How to give dynamic tooltip based when i focusing on particular div background color is red using DOJO in BPM

Tags: dojo, tooltip, business-process-management

I am showing some div, In that div have some red color background and other div have different background color. here all div's have same id's and same classes.

I want to give tool tip for the div's when i focusing on, but here that div have background color is red then that div only i want show tool tip, other div i don't want to show tool tip.

Based on background color i want to show the tool tip.

Comment: can your create jsfiddle for it...whatever you have tried so far...

Comment: You should use classes for that. Your can target divs with those particular classes easy. Ofcource you can manually loop through all your nodes on the page and check out the background color but that will only lead to more headache and probably ugly code.